# Why is the winning shot not showing?

Tags: c++

I created a simple tic-tac-toe. When the player gets the winning shot (for example you got 2 X in a row and all you need is one, and you enter it), the program immediately says:

> "someone won"

(I am still trying to figure out, how to say the name of the player who won.)

Without turning "3" to "X" (let's say the last number is 3).

If I enter 3, "3" should turn to "X" and leave "3 X (X X X)". Instead it only leaves "2 (X X 3)" and immediately says "someone won". How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//board numbers
char numbers[10] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

//structure of players
struct playersinfo
{
int playersnumber;
string player1name, player2name, playersturn;
char player1mark, player2mark;
};

playersinfo players;

//prototype of progress, drawboard, oneWon and twoWon
int progress();
void drawboard();
bool oneWon();
bool twoWon();

int main()
{
//assigns i to progress;
int i, j = 1;
char choice;

//assign players mark
players.player1mark = 'X';
players.player2mark = 'O';

//ask players their name
cout << "Enter player 1's name : ";
cin >> players.player1name;
system("cls");
cout << "Enter player 2's name : ";
cin >> players.player2name;

do
{
    if(j == 1)
    {
        players.playersturn = players.player1name;
        players.playersnumber = 1;
    }
    else if(j == 2)
    {
        players.playersturn = players.player2name;
        players.playersnumber = 2;
    }

    drawboard();
    cout << '\t' <<players.playersturn << " enter a number : ";
    cin >> choice;
    if(choice == numbers[1])
    {
        if(players.playersnumber == 1)
            numbers[1] = players.player1mark;
        else
            numbers[1] = players.player2mark;
        //increment j
        j++;
        if(j == 3)
            j -= 2;
    }
    if(choice == numbers[2])
    {
        if(players.playersnumber == 1)
            numbers[2] = players.player1mark;
        else
            numbers[2] = players.player2mark;
        //increment j
        j++;
        if(j == 3)
            j -= 2;
    }
    if(choice == numbers[3])
    {
        if(players.playersnumber == 1)
            numbers[3] = players.player1mark;
        else
            numbers[3] = players.player2mark;
        //increment j
        j++;
        if(j == 3)
            j -= 2;
    }
    if(choice == numbers[4])
    {
        if(players.playersnumber == 1)
            numbers[4] = players.player1mark;
        else
            numbers[4] = players.player2mark;
        //increment j
        j++;
        if(j == 3)
            j -= 2;
    }
    if(choice == numbers[5])
    {
        if(players.playersnumber == 1)
            numbers[5] = players.player1mark;
        else
            numbers[5] = players.player2mark;
        //increment j
        j++;
        if(j == 3)
            j -= 2;
    }
    if(choice == numbers[6])
    {
        if(players.playersnumber == 1)
            numbers[6] = players.player1mark;
        else
            numbers[6] = players.player2mark;
        //increment j
        j++;
        if(j == 3)
            j -= 2;
    }
    if(choice == numbers[7])
    {
        if(players.playersnumber == 1)
            numbers[7] = players.player1mark;
        else
            numbers[7] = players.player2mark;
        //increment j
        j++;
        if(j == 3)
            j -= 2;
    }
    if(choice == numbers[8])
    {
        if(players.playersnumber == 1)
            numbers[8] = players.player1mark;
        else
            numbers[8] = players.player2mark;
        //increment j
        j++;
        if(j == 3)
            j -= 2;

    }
    if(choice == numbers[9])
    {
        if(players.playersnumber == 1)
            numbers[9] = players.player1mark;
        else
            numbers[9] = players.player2mark;
        //increment j
        j++;
        if(j == 3)
            j -= 2;
    }

    //check progress
    i = progress();

    if(i == -1)
    {
        cout << "\n\n\t\tGame is tied up";
        break;
    }
}while(i != 1);

//congratulate player
if(i == 1)
{

}

cin.ignore();
cin.get();
return 0;
}

//definitions of IsTied, IsOver and drawboard

/*********************************
1  = Game is over
0  = Game is sill in progress 
-1 = Game is tied up 
*********************************/
int progress()
{
if(numbers[1] == numbers[2] && numbers[2] == numbers[3])
    return 1;
else if(numbers[4] == numbers[5] && numbers[5] == numbers[6])
    return 1;
else if(numbers[7] == numbers[8] && numbers[8] == numbers[9])
    return 1;
else if(numbers[1] == numbers[4] && numbers[4] == numbers[7])
    return 1;
else if(numbers[2] == numbers[5] && numbers[5] == numbers[8])
    return 1;
else if(numbers[3] == numbers[6] && numbers[6] == numbers[9])
    return 1;
else if(numbers[7] == numbers[5] && numbers[5] == numbers[3])
    return 1;
else if(numbers[9] == numbers[5] && numbers[5] == numbers[9])
    return 1;
else if(numbers[1] != '1' && numbers[2] != '2' && numbers[3] != '3'
    && numbers[4] != '4' && numbers[5] != '5' && numbers[6] != '6'
    && numbers[7] != '7' && numbers[8] != '8' && numbers[9] != '9')
        return -1;
else 
    return 0;
}
/****************************
FUNCTION THAT DRAWS THE BOARD
****************************/
void drawboard()
{
//clear system screen
system("cls");

cout << "\n\n\t\tTic Tac Toe\n\n";
cout << '\t' <<players.player1name << " = (X) --- " << players.player2name << " = (O)" << endl <<     endl;
cout << '\t' << "     |     |     " << endl;
cout << '\t' << "  " << numbers[1] << "  |  " << numbers[2] << "  |  " << numbers[3] << "  " << endl;
cout << '\t' << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
cout << '\t' << "     |     |     " << endl;
cout << '\t' << "  " << numbers[4] << "  |  " << numbers[5] << "  |  " << numbers[6] << "  " << endl;
cout << '\t' << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
cout << '\t' << "     |     |     " << endl;
cout << '\t' << "  " << numbers[7] << "  |  " << numbers[8] << "  |  " << numbers[9] << "  " << endl;
cout << '\t' << "     |     |     " << endl;
}
```

Comment: Wild guess: you first check if the game is won (and quit) then draw/update the board. If the game is won, the board is not updated. Instead you should check for game is won after you update and draw the new board.

Comment: you can use sleep method to wait for a while before showing message. like, this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(x)); P.S. include "chrono" and "thread" header for this.

Comment: You should start by stepping through in a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I made a java program to do this in college, I don't know how to program it in C++ but basically, to find out who won, you get a boolean which is true when it's player 1s go and false when it's player 2s go. That way when someone wins you can make the program look at the boolean and that will tell you who made the last move.

To solve the fact it says someone won before it puts in the final X just put the code that checks if they won to run after the code that puts down the X

Answer (score 0):

```
do
{
    if(j == 1)
    {
        players.playersturn = players.player1name;
        players.playersnumber = 1;
    }
    else if(j == 2)
    {
        players.playersturn = players.player2name;
        players.playersnumber = 2;
    }

    drawboard();         // 4. this point is not reached with final board configuration
    cout << '\t' <<players.playersturn << " enter a number : ";
    cin >> choice;       // 1. user makes winning move

    //check progress
    i = progress();      // 2. game ended (i=1)

    if(i == -1)
    {
        cout << "\n\n\t\tGame is tied up";
        break;
    }
}while(i != 1);          // 3. program exits this while

// dirty-fix: just a drawboard here:
drawboard();
```